# PersistentVolumeClaim Pending for NFS Volume

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

What specific changes need to be made to the `yaml` below in order to get the `PersistentVolumeClaim` to bind to the `PersistentVolume`?

An EC2 instance in the same VPC subnet as the Kubernetes worker nodes has an ip of 10.0.0.112 and and has been configured to act as an NFS server in the /nfsfileshare path.

### Creating the PersistentVolume

We created a PersistentVolume pv01 with `pv-volume-network.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: "/nfsfileshare"
    server: "10.0.0.112"
```

and by typing:

```
kubectl create -f pv-volume-network.yaml
```

Then when we type `kubectl get pv pv01`, the `pv01` PersistentVolume shows a STATUS of "Available".

### Creating the PersistentVolumeClaim

Then we created a PersistentVolumeClaim named `` with `pv-claim.yaml`:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And by typing:

```
kubectl create -f pv-claim.yaml
```

### STATUS is Pending

But then when we type `kubectl get pvc my-pv-claim`, we see that the STATUS is Pending.  The STATUS remains as Pending for as long as we continued to check back.

Note this OP is different than [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556363/kubernetes-nfs-persistentvolumeclaim-has-status-pending), because this problem persists even with quotes around the NFS IP and the path.

Why is this PVC not binding to the PV?  What specific changes need to be made to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I diagnosed the problem by typing `kubectl describe pvc my-pv-claim` and looking in the Events section of the results.

Then, based on the reported Events, I was able to fix this by changing `storageClassName: manual` to `storageClassName: slow`.

The problem was that the PVC's StorageClassName did not meet the requirement that it match the class specified in the PV.